# Mandar dos variable de un radio y un select mediante JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Quiero mandar dos variables usando `JQuery`,
La primera variable se va a seleccionar mediante un RADIO y la segunda Variable mediante un `SELECT` y ahora quiero que esas dos variables se manden a otro archivo, para que pueda subir esas dos variables a la BD

```
<form action="cuenta.php" method="post" name="regisConsulta" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="radio" name="cosas_ID" value="<?=$cosa_ID;?>">

<select name="modo_tipo" class="status" >
    <option value="<?=$modo_ID;?>"><?=$tipo;?></option>
</select>
```

Conseguí un script, pero solo manda una variable(LA DEL SELECT), pero no logro hacer que mande las dos(radio y select).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select.status').on('change',function () {
    var decision = $(this).val();
        var id = $('td.myid').html();
    alert(decision);
    $.ajax({    type: "POST",
             url: "guarda_modo.php",
             data: {decision: decision, id: id },
             success: function(msg) {
                 $('#autosavenotify').text(msg);
             }
  })
  });
});
```

Comment: Disculpa, no queda muy clara tu pregunta ¿buscas hacerlo por AJAX o solo mediante el envío de la forma? Por la manera en que lo envías ( con un `POST` de tu forma) en tu segunda página `cuenta.php` los resultados de tu forma aparecerán en el objeto `$_POST`. Si quieres acceder, lo hacer por medio del nombre ejemplo: `$cosas_id = $_POST["cosas_ID"];`

Comment: Si busco hacerlo con ajax, porque quiero que mande esas dos variables, sin tener que apretar un boton de enviar datos y solo quiero selecionar esos dos campos y que se envie las variable de cada campo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu ejemplo se está haciendo el envío en el evento change del select, y al estar haciendo $(this).val() por eso te funciona para el select. Si quieres seguir por esta línea, cambia

```
var id = $('td.myid').html();
```

por

```
var id = $('input[name=cosas_ID]:checked').val();
```

Esto toma en cuenta que el radio box está seleccionado, quizás es algo que debes validar.

Lo mejor sería usar form.serialize() para serializar en un objeto todos los campos y sus valores, y luego pasarlos a la función ajax.